# Web page download progress with percentage

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i saw that flash website can be develop to show percentage of loading page. when web page is downloading in client machine then a percentage is shown and show much content is downloading in client machine. so i just want to know the same effect can be achieve in asp.net website where we will show the percentage of the page content is downloading in client machine with the help of JQuery when page will be requested by user.

please discuss how to achieve it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GMail uses a loading bar as well. Here is a blog posting on how to make one for your own website, might be handy:

http://yensdesign.com/2008/11/how-to-create-a-stylish-loading-bar-as-gmail-in-javascript/